# SSH tunnel SOCKS5 or VPN after Tor with Tails

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, vpn, ssh, torsocks

I am using Tails 1.2.2 as OS.
I need to use anything to hide the fact I'm using Tor, so far I've tried socks5 with proxychains but the permission is denied when I check with curl.
SSH tunnel are also not working with ssh or torify, simply Tails doesn't allow me to do anything!! Does anybody know something about it?

Comment: From who you have to hide your Tor activity? From your ISP or the server that you connect to? Read here [VPN tails support](https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/vpn_support) I hope that this will help you!